# Iteration over handlebar helper

Tags: iteration, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Is it possible to iterate over at handlebar helper which return an array of objects?

this is what the helper returns:
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

there is 5 objects in the array and each has 2 keys a "year" and a "value".

The helper looks like this: {{getPeriodYears 'test' 'some Other Text'}}

I have tried this:

```
{{#getPeriodYears 'text' 'some Other Text'}}
<div>{{year}}</div>
<div>{{value}}</div>
{{/getPeriodYears}}
```

Which just prints this on top of the page: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: what is ur helper code?

Comment: Handlebars.registerHelper('getPeriodYears ', function (value1, value2) {
var data = filterData(value1, value2, allDataArray);

(data prints [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object])

return data;
});